# Why are dynamic inline script tags evaluated before ending the context?

Tags: javascript, html

Can someone point me to the relevant standard part about this behavior ?

http://arcanis.github.io/dynamic-scripts/

Basically, two things are surprising me : I always thought that dynamic script tags where always loaded right after returning from the first executor (as if the browser was doing an internal setImmediate). However, in this example :

- The inline tags are executed immediatly in the window scope (they do not wait for the end of the current execution stream)
- The remote tags are executed after every other tag, even if they have been appended before them

Is this behavior correct ? Chrome, Firefox and even IE11 get the same result (except that IE is not triggering the dynamically appended remote script), so I'm probably missing something.

---

*Short code sample for reference :*

```
<script>
    log("Starting standard script tag ...");
    var s = document.createElement( 'script' );
    s.appendChild( document.createTextNode( 'log("Executing dynamically appended inline script tag")' ) );
    document.querySelector( 'head' ).appendChild( s );
    log("Ending standard script tag");
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

At first I need to mention that I didn't have time to look at the specs precisely, so I probably interpret it wrong.

But looking at the section **[prepare a script](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/scripting-1.html#prepare-a-script)** you have the following statements:

> [...]
>      15. Then, the first of the following options that describes the situation must be followed:
>      [...]
>      <del>**If the element does not have a src attribute, and the element has been flagged as "parser-inserted", and either the parser that created the script is an XML parser or it's an HTML parser whose script nesting level is not greater than one, and the Document of the HTML parser or XML parser that created the script element has a style sheet that is blocking scripts**
>
>      The element is the pending parsing-blocking script of the Document of the parser that created the element. (There can only be one such script per Document at a time.)</del>
>
> <del>Set the element's "ready to be parser-executed" flag. The parser will handle executing the script.</del> 
>      [...]
>      **Otherwise**
>      The user agent must immediately execute the script block, even if other scripts are already executing.

I understand it that way:

- The programmatically created element, matches the *Otherwise* condition as the other conditions (also those I omitted) wont match, and because of this the script has to be executed immediately.

But as I said, I had no time to read the whole thing in detail, I will do so the next days. But for now this is probably something that could help you already.

**EDIT**
After i read the the first quoted condition a second time I realized that I indeed didn't read it carefully (`[...]and the Document of the HTML parser or XML parser that created the script element has a style sheet that is blocking scripts[...]`), so I marked with `<del>`.

Comment: That's why you always should put your <script> tags (with src or not) at the end of your body tag.